# doing trivial search and replace via a regex

Tags: haskell

I am using [regex-tdfa](https://github.com/ChrisKuklewicz/regex-tdfa) which installs easiely with stack

As seen in the docs, using a regex predicate is simple:

```
λ> emailRegex = "[a-zA-Z0-9+._-]+@[a-zA-Z-]+\\.[a-z]+"
λ> "my email is email@email.com" =~ emailRegex :: Bool
```

How can I search and replace with this lib ?
I would like for example, to filter out characters from a string.

I can't `fmap` on a string with the `=~`operator since it expects strings and not characters as input, which is why I am stuck.

Many thanks.

Comment: From the readme, "Replacement
regex-tdfa does not provide find-and-replace."

Comment: The GitHub repository specifies "*regex-tdfa does not provide find-and-replace.*"

Comment: Thanks for your constructive feedback Michael. Of course I read that it does not do search and replace which is why I was posting this.

Comment: Perhaps the `AllMatches [] (MatchOffset, MatchLength)` instance of `RegexContext` will get you where you need to go. Although I suppose you'll have to consider what to do about overlapping matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `(=~)` form that returns the "before", "matched", and "after" parts.  To replace only the first occurrence, use:

```
replace1 :: String -> String -> String -> String
replace1 pat repl str
  = let (a,b,c) = str =~ pat :: (String, String, String)
    in  a ++ repl ++ c
```

To replace all non-overlapping occurrences, use a recursive solution.

```
replace :: String -> String -> String -> String
replace pat repl str
  = case str =~ pat :: (String, String, String) of
      (rest, "", "") -> rest
      (a, b, c) -> a ++ repl ++ replace pat repl c
```

If you want something fancier than fixed-text replacement, you can change the type of `repl` from `String` to `String -> String` in the obvious way, or use the "get first match and submatches" form, if you also want `repl :: String -> [String] -> String` to act on the submatches.

Of course, if you really want to "filter out characters from a string", then a better solution is:

```
filter (not . isDigit) "N0 0ne 7ike5 num83r5"
```